# How to delete ghost user on Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I just remove one user and it appears a ghost user, is it possible to remove ghost user?

I read that a ghost user represents all deleted users. Issues and comments created by any deleted user will be transferred to the ghost user.

But is it not possible to remove it?

Comment: from Gitlab: Instead of being deleted, these records will be moved to a system-wide "Ghost User", whose sole purpose is to act as a container for such records.

When a user is deleted from an abuse report or spam log, these associated records are not ghosted and will be removed, along with any groups the user is a sole owner of. Administrators can also request this behaviour when deleting users from the API or the admin area.

[API about deletion](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#user-deletion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(...) for future references: [API of GitLab doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#user-deletion)

**User deletion**

Deletes a user. Available only for administrators. This is an idempotent function, calling this function for a non-existent user id still returns a status code 200 OK. The JSON response differs if the user was actually deleted or not. In the former the user is returned and in the latter not.

> DELETE /users/:id

Parameters:

> id (required) - The ID of the user
>
> hard_delete (optional) - If true, contributions that would usually be
>   moved to the ghost user will be deleted instead, as well as groups
>   owned solely by this user.

Comment: Really thanks!, But how can I know the id of the ghost user?

Comment: Sorry but there is no info on deleting ghost user, if you wanted to full delete some user posts now on ghost user probably will need to write directly to GitLab

Answer (score 7):

I've had a similar problem when playing with gitlab+ldap installation and removing test users, so here is how I removed the Ghost User eventually.

First check whether everything is ok with GitLab (optional step):

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:check
```

Execute GitLab console:

```
sudo gitlab-rails console
```

Using the console find the the id of the ghost user and delete it:

```
user = User.find_by(username: "ghost")
User.delete(user.id)
```

If the user is removed then output would be 1, if 0 then user is not removed.